# Running ts-node scripts that import css modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-node

How can I run scripts that import css modules?

I'm writing a typescript migration script that I'd like to run via `ts-node`.  Ideally, my codebase would be organized such that the script's dependencies never touch React components, but that's not the case.  The script ultimately imports React components and thus css modules, so `ts-node` fails because it doesn't understand css modules:

```
RenderableInline.tsx(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module './styles/RenderableInline.module.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Only webpack understands how to build css modules, since I've configured it via a `css-loader`.

The only precedent for this I've found is jest, which has some configuration option for mocking out css modules so it can import these files without error: https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack.

How can I run a typescript script that has dependencies on css modules?  Is there someway to do this via `ts-node`?  Or does webpack have some script running feature?

Answer (score 0):

Add a global `.d.ts` file that provides direction on how `.css` files should be handled.

Such as `src/global.d.ts` with the following contents:

```
declare module '*.module.css' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

May also be helpful to add the [`typescript-plugin-css-modules`](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules#typescript-plugin-css-modules) plugin. Note though that this only helps during development using VSCode but has no effect during compilation.

---

While I generally got this working, I am still facing problems to get this to work correctly with [`ts-node-dev`](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) - probably related to `ts-node` not loading these type files by default [Missing Types](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types). Unfortunately even using the `--files` directive, I couldn't get this to work.